# How to reuse view controller objects in swift with navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, navigation

My app has a user profile page and I can move from that profile to record and from record to profile etc (like instagram, facebook). Such transitions can be endless. I use Navigation Controller with performSegue. How can I reuse view controller objects so that I don't have to create new ones every time I transition? Otherwise, after 25 iterations, I run out of RAM.

Comment: can you share some code snapshot or UI?

Comment: For example when User tap on avatar:

@objc func openProfileSegue(notification: NSNotification){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openProfileSegue", sender: self)
    }

So, I open new Segue and create new object of view controller (and it took 20 mb of RAM)

Comment: Read about "singleton" i think it will help you and solve your issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try to find some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find profile view controller and pop on that view controller. Please see below code.

```
   for viewController in self.navigationController?.viewControllers ?? [] {
        if viewController is ProfileViewController {
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

And for the animation you can use below code so animation look like pushviewController

```
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
    self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```